# how to do sequencing in vertica?

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a table with customer_id's and order_id's that I'd like to sequence based on customer_id.  How is this done in Vertica SQL?

```
c_id  o_id 
1     1
2     3
1     4
2     5
3     6
3     7
```

I'd like:

```
c_id  o_id  seq
1     1     1
1     4     2
2     3     1
2     5     2
3     6     1
3     7     2
```

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know Vertica supports (standard) window functions, so the following should work:

```
select c_id, 
       o_id,
       row_number() over (partition by c_id order by o_id) as seq
from the_table
order by c_id, o_id
```

Comment: From OP's expected result it seems that s/he wants to `ORDER BY c_id, o_id` and then have `12 12 ...` sequence.